# System Services are not available design fault help needed

Tags: android, listactivity

I have gone through the other posts and found that I am doing what I should not do by initializing an activity via new operator.

Basically I have two activity classes a PlayListActivity(extending ListActivity) and a MainActivity. I am having a public function in PlayListActivity that I need to call in the MainActivity. How should I achieve that? Is there any pattern I need to follow? Also I have a problem that I want to initiate this function(definition residing in ListActivity) when a button is clicked in my Activity layout without via intent. Is there a way? and if yes then please do show me with an example.

A Newbie.

Answer (score 0):

2 common ways to do this:

Frist option: extend Application and expose interfaces between the 2 activities there:

`public class MyApplication extends Application {`

```
private static MyApplication singleton;
public ListAcvitiy2MainActivityItf ltm;
public MainActivity2ListActivityItf mtl;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    singleton = this;
}

public MyApplicatoin getInstance(){
    return singleton;
}
```

`}`

in each interface, declare the methods you want to expose:

```
public interface ListAcvitiy2MainActivityItf {
    public void someMethod();
}
```

and declare MyApplication in the manifest:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/launch_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:name="MyApplication">
```

Second option: define a Handler in each activity and use Handler.sendMessage to send messages between the activities:

private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {...

Comment: Okay I think I will try the second one... So handler is basically a class but as in what will be the contents of it?? and how can it be achieved??